# Root user on linux-based embedded systems

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded, root

I'm involved in the task of creating a root filesystem for Beagleebone running Linux. Usually the filesystem is generated and configured with a single root user (for example with buildroot), which is the only user of the system. Does it mean that all the commands and applications are executed with root privileges (being that the only user of the system)? Isn't this a security issue? Would it be better to create a non-root user? What is the usual practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a linux system there are many system users apart from root which may be used for specific purposes. If your embedded system is some kind of autonomous system (eg. a robot) and doesn't expose any services on a network or some kind of direct physical access to users, there's not so much to worry about. If it does then you should just check if the softwares in question really require root access or not. You can always create less privileged users to run them on your behalf, if they are not really made considering all security implications.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspbery Pi Debian comes with root + a pi user "pre-installed", who has sudo rights. Modern Unix systems does not enable "native root login", so extra user is a need.

If your device is somehow connected to internet, I mean, there is a chance to reach it from internet or a wider LAN, you should follow some security guide lines (e.g. no root login). But if not, say, your device has no LAN access at all, don't worry such things.